# Show that $P(\text{at least one }A_i)=P(A_1)+P(A_2)+P(A_3)-2P(A_1 \cap A_2)$

Tags: probability

If $A_1, A_2, A_3$ are three events and $P(A_1 \cap A_2) = P( A_1 \cap A_3) \neq 0$ but $P(A_2 \cap A_3) = 0$, show that $P(\text{at least one }A_i)=P(A_1)+P(A_2)+P(A_3)-2P(A_1 \cap A_2)$.

This is what I have so far:

$P(\text{at least one } A_i)=P(A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3)$.

Now we know that $P(A \cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A \cap B)$.

Apply this to $(A_1 \cup A_2)$ and $A_3$.

$P(A_1 \cup A_2)=P(A_1)P(A_2)-P(A_1 \cap A_2)
\implies P(A_1 \cap A_2)=P(A_1)P(A_2)-P(A_1 \cup A_2)$.

Not sure where to go from here? Or if someone could point out where I'm going wrong, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hint:  for arbitrary events try to write out $P(A_1\cap A_2\cap A_3)$.Then use your extra information to eliminate and combine terms.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the image below (sorry for my poor drawing skills, the red regions should be the same size). Notice if we add each of the three circles, then we are double-counting the overlapping regions. So we must subtract out for each of the overlapping regions. Since the overlapping regions have the same probability though, so can just subtract out twice of just one of the overlapping regions. This will give you your result.

[image]

Comment: Just wanted to note there is a slight caveat in that the diagram isn't perfectly representative of the sets in the case that (1) the sample space is uncountable or (2) we have a finite/countable sample space that contains elements that have a zero probability of occurring.